# Custom Fonts - wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress, when you make a blog entry, it displays the date year etc of that blog.

Is there a php/jquery script that can take any kind of title and render an image of that?

In other words if the entry data is "20th july 2010" how would I get it to render each of the three items in a different font/image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all no to the jQuery text-to-image generator.

Now, what you are talking about is a custom theme for wordpress.  A great tutorial for that can be found here: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/building-custom-wordpress-theme/

You also mentioned text-to-image generation, I would look here: http://www.phptutorial.info/learn/create_images/ to learn how to do that.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks on that info. Close to what I want. I am basically looking for a script that will take say an h1 - title and turn it into a custom font. Say going from georgia to baskerville. I don't want to have to keep creating the images, just that if the user types a "word" that script automaticlaly turns it into the unique font.

Comment: You are looking at a thing like sIFR then (http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr) that is one of the more popular solutions.  There are others available but this is my favorite.  Here is a demo of it: http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/beta2/demo/

Comment: yeah something like that - Is there not one without the flash part? or rather, are there disadvantages to having a swf vs an image? Thanks for the response! :)

Comment: Usually I would say stay away from swf.  But sIFR swf files are not very large files and do not take long to load, and it handles the user not having flash/having flash turned off very well.  Really there is no negative to using swf.  There are other options like WEFT and Cufon that embed the font, but in my opinion which is strictly an opinion would rather use a swf then embed fonts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of font replacement techniques out there in general. If you dive into the template files you might be able to accomplish the font changes with CSS classes.  Unless I am not completely understanding the question.

Comment: I thought there was a way to take a regular html entry, say a title, then the script creates an image(using a custom font.) rather than embedding the font.

Comment: Nope, if your user doesnt have a font you must embed it: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WEFT.mspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not a text-to-image converter, just some fonts you can add to your website. Check this http://code.google.com/webfonts

Comment: That's pretty neat. Defo keep it in mind. These fonts that I am supposed to use are very custom:(